# What will be the path of liquibase changlog.xml which exists in jar to include into current project

Tags: liquibase

I've a jar which has its own changelog.xml under src/main/resources, and I want to include that changelog.xml into my current project. 
Example :

Project1 ->
                 src/main/resources
                                            ->project1.changelog-1.0.xml

Project 2 ->
                 src/main/resources
                                            ->project2.changelog-1.0.xml

What will be the path of project2.changelog-1.0.xml to include into project1.changelog-1.0.xml ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem.
Use **maven-dependency-plugin** to unpack the project2 jar and then use **maven-resources-plugin** to extract the project2.changelog-1.0.xml  into project1->src->main->resources.

After extracting use  tag to include project2.changelog-1.0.xml.  in project1.changelog-1.0.xml.

This solved my problem. I'm not sure if this is expensive but i think it's a good solution.

Comment: can you share you pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/include.html).  Assuming Project 1 has Project 2 as a dependency, you should be able to list it simply as:

`project2.changelog-1.0.xml`

Comment: It didn't work. I'm getting SEVERE 2/11/14 2:02 PM:liquibase: Error thrown as a SAXException: project2.changelog-1.0.xml does not exist
liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: project2.changelog-1.0.xml does not exist

Comment: Yes, i do have maven dependency added to the project1.

Comment: Can you add the relevant lines of project2.changelog.xml?  It's looking for project1.changelog-1.0.xml, not project1.changelog.xml.

Comment: <include  file="project2.changelog-1.0.xml"/> . This is what i'm doing. But it is a relative path. I might need to provide and absolute path.

Comment: No, you need a path relative to the classpath.  Make sure the project2 jar is on your classpath, and the project2-changelog-1.0.xml file is in there.

Comment: What will be the relative path here ?